# Powershell - save value from hashtable to a @{}

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-appservice

i have some azure app service and each one have their config. I would like to get that setting and store it into a variable @{}. So when i run:

```
    $srcapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "myrg" -Name "myapp"
    $srcapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
```

i got the config in a Hashtable:

```
Name   Value
----   -----
Tetst3 78910
Test2  4567
Test   1234
```

after that i would like to put it in a @{} to define the hashtable:

```
@{"Test"='1234';"Test2"='4567';"Tetst3"='78910'}
```

is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Well what you want seem to be a stringyfied pscustomobject ? so assuming `$srcapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings` is actually a hashtable and not an array of hastables you could just do `[string] [pscustomobject] $srcapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon it is not a pscustomobject . If i run your command i got . Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair

Comment: It sounds like the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$srcapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings` returns an object of type `System.Collections.Generic.IList[Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair]`:

```
$webapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "myrg" -Name "myapp";

write-host ($webapp.SiteConfig | gm -Name "AppSettings").Definition;
# System.Collections.Generic.IList[
#    Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair
# ] AppSettings {get;set;}

$appsettings = $webapp.SiteConfig.AppSettings

$appsettings
# Name   Value
# ----   -----
# Tetst3 78910
# Test2  4567
# Test   1234
```

Note you can also make one for testing like this:

```
$appsettings = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair]] @(
    [Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair]::new("Tetst3", "78910"),
    [Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair]::new("Test2",  "4567"),
    [Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.NameValuePair]::new("Test",   "1234")
);

$appsettings
# Name   Value
# ----   -----
# Tetst3 78910
# Test2  4567
# Test   1234
```

To convert this to a `System.Collections.Hashtable` you could do something like this:

```
$hashtable = $appsettings | foreach-object `
    -Begin   { $tmp = @{}; } `
    -Process { $tmp.Add($_.Name, $_.Value); } `
    -End     { return $tmp; }

$hashtable | Format-Table -AutoSize;
# Name   Value
# ----   -----
# Tetst3 78910
# Test2  4567
# Test   1234
```

Sure, it *looks* the same when it gets serialised for output, but they're completely different underlying types in memory...

If you *specifically* want a stringified version of the hashtable you can do this:

```
$psobject = new-object pscustomobject -Property $hashtable;
$output = "$psobject";
$output
# @{Tetst3=78910; Test2=4567; Test=1234}
```

*or*, if you need it to be stringified *exactly* like your example, you can do this:

```
$result = "@{" + `
    (($hashtable.GetEnumerator() | foreach-object {
         "`"$($_.Name)`"=`"$($_.Value)`""
    }) -join ";") + `
"}";

$result
# @{"Tetst3"="78910";"Test2"="4567";"Test"="1234"}
```

But be aware that it will probably break if your data has special characters like quotes in it...

Comment: Hi thanks!!! The last example fit my request. Now i have it stringified, to reconvert $result it in hashtable?? The process is the same?

Comment: If you're persisting the data and rehydrating it later you should use something like ```ConvertTo-Json``` and ```ConvertFrom-Json``` - the stringified version won't round-trip in all cases so you're better off avoiding it.

Comment: i'm getting Cannot convert the @{"Tetst3"="78910";"Test2"="4567";"Test"="1234"} value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable"

Comment: i solved with this code. I found i here on stack overflow:


$Dictionary = @{} # Split input string into pairs $result.Split(';') |ForEach-Object { # Split each pair into key and value $key,$value = $_.Split('=') # Populate $Dictionary $Dictionary[$key] = $value }

Comment: I’d strongly recommend you look at the json conversion functions - the format you’re using has issues - what happens for example if an appsetting’s value is something like ```aaa”;”bbb”=“ccc```? Your serialisation process won’t recover the original hashtable, but something else instead…

Comment: thanks i will do a test